# How do you access properties of elements within an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get the html elements, except the TR and TD and get their ID attributes. The strange thing is, when i try to get the elements by document.getElementById("someId") using alert function, something shows up. But when i captured the element and use the direct call to id, it tells undefined.

Here's my code in JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ss7ykqyh/

Sample HTML:

```
    <tr>
        <td> <input id="button1" /> </td>
        <td> <input id="button2" /> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <input id="button3" /> </td>
        <td> <input id="button4" /> </td>
    </tr>

</table>


<input value="clone me!" type="button" id="btnCloneMe" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

my script:

```
function myFunction() {

    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var rows = table.rows;


    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        var noOfCells = rows[i].cells.length;
        alert("no of cells: " + noOfCells);

        for(var j = 0; j < noOfCells; j++){

            var cell = rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
            alert("inside cell: " + cell.id);

            var element = document.getElementById("button1");
            alert(element.id);

        }

    }



}
```

This is one approach, I'm thinking as well if there is any better approach to capturing all html elements except TD and TR

Also, is it a violation to just post the JSFiddle url, or do i need to post the codes directly in the query altogether? 
Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is telling undefined, because you're trying to get attribute **id** of text which you have obtained with .innerHTML. Instead of `var cell = rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;` try `var cell = rows[i].cells[j].children;`. Now your cell variable will contain an array of elements. You can iterate through each one of them and get their id. It could look like this

```
var cell = rows[i].cells[j].children;
for (var k = 0; k < cell.length; k++) {
    alert("inside cell: " + cell[k].id);
}
```

Comment: this approach totally nailed it. I was trying to get not only the 'input element' but as well the other elements INSIDE the cell. thank you so much. Others answers were useful too specially the querySelector! :)

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML returns a string, not an object, and as such it has no ID property

```
var cell = rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
alert("inside cell: " + cell.id);
```

see how `cell` is a string

You could just remove the `innerHTML` call, but the cells have no ID ?

```
var cell = rows[i].cells[j]; // returns empty string ?
```

I'm guessing you want the ID of the buttons, and then you'd have to find them first, one way to do that is using querySelector

```
var cell = rows[i].cells[j].querySelector('input');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ss7ykqyh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pure Js solution, then try this one

```
function myFunction() {

    var elems= document.querySelectorAll('table tr td input');

    for (var i = 0;i<elems.length;i++)
    {
        debugger;
        alert(elems[i].id);             
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ss7ykqyh/5/

Comment: sir this is quite useful for my future endeavors, but what i found here is its quite general. How do i attack this when i want to target a specific table with an id 'table1'? coz as i understand it .querySelector('table tr td input') would mean targeting all table elements, then its td, then its td, then inputs..

Comment: querySelector works pretty much like the jQuery selectors. If you want to point specifically to table1, then you can use:

querySelector('#table1 tr td input')